# Call external matlab function in Spark

Tags: python, matlab, apache-spark

I am trying to distribute some programs to a local cluster I built using Spark. The aim of this project is to pass some data to each worker and pass the data to an external matlab function to process and collect the data back to master node. I met problem of how to call matlab function. Is that possible for Spark to call external function? In other word, could we control each function parallelized in Spark to search local path of each node to execute external function.
Here is a small test code:

### run.py

```
import sys
from operator import add

from pyspark import SparkContext
import callmatlab

def run(a):
    # print '__a'
    callmatlab.sparktest()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonWordCount")
    output = sc.parallelize(range(1,2)).map(run)
    print output
    sc.stop()
```

### sparktest.py

```
import matlab.engine as eng
import numpy as np
eng = eng.start_matlab()

def sparktest():
    print "-----------------------------------------------"
    data = eng.sparktest()
    print "----the return data:\n", type(data), data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sparktest()
```

### submit spark

```
    #!/bin/bash
    path=/home/zzz/ProgramFiles/spark

    $path/bin/spark-submit \
    --verbose \
    --py-files $path/hpc/callmatlab.py $path/hpc/sparktest.m \
    --master local[4] \
    $path/hpc/run.py \
    README.md
```

It seems Spark asks all attached .py files shown as parameters of --py-files, however, Spark does not recognize sparktest.m.
I do not know how to continue. Could anyone give me some advice? Does Spark allow this way? Or any recommendation of other distributed python framework?

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with matlab, so asking: what is sparktest.m? I think you do not need it. Secondly, you can try putting them in a .zip file. From documentation: For Python, you can use the --py-files argument of spark-submit to add .py, .zip or .egg files to be distributed with your application. If you depend on multiple Python files we recommend packaging them into a .zip or .egg.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying to answer my question. I use a different way to solve this problem. I uploaded the matlab files and data need to call and load to a path in the node file system. And the python just add the path and call it using matlab.engine module.
So my callmatlab.py becomes

```
import matlab.engine as eng
import numpy as np
import os
eng = eng.start_matlab()

def sparktest():
    print "-----------------------------------------------"
    eng.addpath(os.path.join(os.getenv("HOME"), 'zzz/hpc/'),nargout=0)
    data = eng.sparktest([12, 1, 2])
    print data
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I do not see any reason to pass on sparktest.m. 
Secondly, recommended way is putting them in a .zip file. From documentation:

> For Python, you can use the --py-files argument of spark-submit to add
>   .py, .zip or .egg files to be distributed with your application. If
>   you depend on multiple Python files we recommend packaging them into a
>   .zip or .egg.

At the end, remember your function will be executed in an executor jvm in a remote m/c, so Spark framework ships function, closure and additional files as part of the job. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the

```
--files
```

option before the sparktest.m .

That tells Spark to ship the sparktest.m file to all workers.

Comment: I tried. Have you did this successfully before? Sparks returned me an error: cannot load main class from JAR file.